# How to access repaint from the main?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d, repaint

I am working on a Java program that basically renders an image from a file source and then paints that image onto a panel (which is on a frame).

Now what I am able to do is invoke a line of code of the form

```
printpanel.getGraphics().drawImage(myimage.globalimage, 0,0, null);
```

where `myimage` is a class that contains the image.

As many of you know, this only prints the image 1 time, and should I resize the frame, the image disappears.

Now the way to fix this would be to put the line into the `repaint` method, but i'm in the `main` method right now so how do I access the definition of the `repaint` method and change it from within the `main` method?

Thanks!

=====================================================================================================

My code:

MAIN CLASS:

```
    package imagetester;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Imagetester 
{



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame printframe = new JFrame("The drawing frame");
        JPanel printpanel = new JPanel();
        printframe.setSize(700,700);
        printpanel.setSize(700,700);
        printframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        printframe.add(printpanel);
        printpanel.setVisible(true);
        printframe.setVisible(true);

        Imageobject myimage = new Imageobject();
        try
        {
            myimage.setImage("word.jpg");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("the image failed!");
        }


        printpanel.getGraphics().drawImage(myimage.globalimage, 0,0, null);
        printpanel.repaint();


        System.out.println("hi");

    }

}
```

myimage class:

```
    package imagetester;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Imageobject 
{
    BufferedImage globalimage;

    public void setImage(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        globalimage = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));

    }

    public void Imagebject()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: is there a tutorial on code formatting? I never seem to be able to format it as I intended it

Comment: When you post your code, just highlight all of it, then click the `{}` button of the editor. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot that made sense!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but if what you want to do is display a panel with an image inside a window, you should subclass JPanel (or whatever other panel you'd like), and override the paintComponent method to paint the image. Something along the lines of:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;

    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting to call `super.paintComponent` ;)

Comment: I like this solution! but was wondering is there a way to avoid creating another class and (more importantly) keeping the logic outside the class: ie by having the calls for painting done in the main method as opposed to the repaint? so that way the things that need to be painted can be periodically changed through external methods as opposed to having a massive repaint method which handles its own logic

Comment: I guess is I mean to ask is there something analogous to repaint.removelines(), and repaint.addlines()? that could be used to remove and add objects that need to be painted (or better yet) is it possible to create inline paint methods (ie change the repaint method temporarily to something else)

Comment: The whole idea of the paint methods is to handle the painting. It shouldn't be controlled from the outside.  This is an OO principle, swing or not.

Comment: @eitanfar i was worried thats where this was going. I think that answers my question then. This I suppose is a paradigm which is better  to perform in another language.

Answer (score 1):

> Now what i am able to do is invoke a line of code of the form
>   `printpanel.getGraphics().drawImage(myimage.globalimage, 0,0, null);`

No don't do that. Your `printPanel` should already have it's `paintComponent` method, with the a `drawImage` in it.

```
Image image;
...
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null) {
        g.drawImage(image, ..., this); // this is the ImageObserver. Should not be null
    }
}
```

Then you can just have a setter for it if you want to change it

```
public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
    repaint();
}
```

Just call that method with the image you want to change

---

### EDIT

There's no way around it. You need to `@Override` the `paintComponent` method of the `JPanel`. When you resize the frame, `repaint()` will automatically be called, leaving the image there. The image should be drawn in the `paintComponent` method. You can have the panel's constructor take an `Image` argument if you want to instantiate that way, with the image from the `ImageObject`

Comment: this definitely makes sense but is there a perhaps more direct solution that can be entirely done from within the main method? While i understand that repaint is traditionally the thing invoked i want to be able to control the repaint from other methods (not just in this example but in general)

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Why can't you just `printPanel.repaint()`? Maybe a code example would help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be doing so much in the `main` method. Seem like you have a lot going on in there. The `main` method should generally for just initializing/starting the program, like just creating the frame and add a main panel or call a method in the class that initializes everything.

Comment: peeksillet, I'm not in the repaint method. The line of code for drawing has been intentionally placed outside it and thus gets deleted during resizing unless i change the repaint definition. My objective is to determine a way to control the repaint definition from outside repaint. Currently the solutions all require an unchanging repaint method whichc contains its own logic for how to draw things: and while that is an excellent way of solving the problem it is a little too limiting for my taste

Comment: First of all don't call your method `repaint()`, as `JPanel` and all other components already have a `repaint()` method. It's confusing, and may cause you problems. Secondly, post some code because I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I think I didn't express myself clearly. I wasn't calling it repaint. What i meant was: I'm either a. trying to create other repaint-like methods that handle painting and fire off whenever repaint is called on some object or b. trying to change the definition of the repaint method of some specified object.

Comment: So basically you what whatever changes made in the `ImageObject` to occur automatically in the `JPanel`?

Answer (score 1):

> As many of you know, this only prints the image 1 time, and should I resize the frame, the image disappears.

What is your requirement when the frame resizes?

1. Do you paint the image at its original size? If so then just use a JLabel with an ImageIcon and add the label to the frame
2. Do you want the image to scale with the size of the frame? Then you need to do custom painting. You can create a custom component as demonstrated in other answers. Or you can use a JLabel with a [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will stretch to fill the space available to the label.